# asciidoc-pdf: How to use custom styles

Tags: asciidoctor

How can I use custom styles (font-size, font-color etc) in asciidoctor-pdf.
I've read the theming guide and tried to add settings ins xxx-theme.yml without any success.
Also the the marked styling (with #) doesn't work in my pdf example.

Comment: Theming is still very alpha-ish. Please post to the mailing list and / or create an issue in github for it.

Answer (score 3):

You should have to create your own YAML theme and then use the `pdf-style` option like this

```sh
$ asciidoctor-pdf src/main.adoc -a pdf-style=themes/my-theme.yml
```

[Documentation here](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/master/docs/theming-guide.adoc#applying-your-theme)

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom style is mandatory if you want a result similar to what you get when exporting to html or epub3, because the default theme do not map default (css/html) styles from asciidoc.

- Create a file with the "-theme.yml" suffix, like "my-theme.yml"
- then insert:

```yaml
extends: default
  role:
    red: 
      font-color: #c5000c
    maroon:
      font-color: #4f2400
    green:
      font-color: #366251
    navy:
      font-color: #4974a5
```

do reference in this yaml all color names along with its respective encoding (the one in this example are not exact), and used like that `[.green]#SomeTextThatSouldLookGreen#` in your *.adoc file.
(I am using [role](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/main/docs/theming-guide.adoc#role) in this sample theme for simplicity but other ways may fit your needs, see the [theming-guide](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/main/docs/theming-guide.adoc) that starts by an explaination about customizing fonts)

- then call it either using command-line options:

  asciidoctor-pdf src/main.adoc -a pdf-style=themes/my-theme.yml

  asciidoctor-pdf src/main.adoc -a pdf-stylesdir=./themes -a pdf-style=my

or by inserting the followinfgspecific tag in your source *.adoc file:

```
:pdf-theme: themes/pdf-theme.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how a `xxx-theme.yml` can be used inside a maven build, you can refer to the [asciidoctor-pdf-with-theme-example](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-examples/tree/master/asciidoctor-pdf-with-theme-example) project. It generates two pdf files (one styled with the yml file and using the default PDF style)

Comment: The provided sample works fine for theming. But still the asciidoc custom stlying like
`== Introduction

This project does something.
[mySuperStyle]#We# just haven't decided what that is yet.` 
does not work.
In HTML add a css with 
`.mySuperStyle {
    font-size: 32px;
}`
would do the job, but adding 
`mySuperStyle:
  font_color: #FF8000
  font_size: 32
  font_style: italic`
in custom-theme.yml has no effect.

I've tried to fix this issue and I think I've got a solution - as @LightGuard suggested I will create an issue and add my Code proposal.

Comment: [github issue](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/pull/350?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container)